# ValueError: zero length field name in format with read and write

Tags: python, linux

Does anybody know if it is possible to avoid the error `ValueError: zero length field` reading/writing from/to a file with Python 2.6.6 as specified in the following:

```
 File "format.py", line 26, in <module>
    for row in write_cols(rows):
  File "format.py", line 19, in write_cols
    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]
  File "format.py", line 19, in <genexpr>
    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
"{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index])
```

into

```
"{0:<{1}}".format(col, widths[index])
```

Coz in older release of python, you need to point out the order of multiple format field.

Comment: Edited my code but it does not work. More details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589550/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-reading-writing-from-to-file

Comment: Make sure you write `"{0:<{1}}".format(col, widths[index])` instead of `"{0:<{1}}".format(col, width=widths[index])`

Comment: Done. I have this error:  for row in write_cols(rows):
  File "format.py", line 11, in write_cols
    return [col_spacer.join("{0:<{1}}".format(col, widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]
  File "format.py", line 11, in <genexpr>
    return [col_spacer.join("{0:<{1}}".format(col, widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Changed in version 2.7: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so '{} {}' is equivalent to '{0} {1}'. from[docs 7.1.3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) @Alessandro Blasetti