# IndexError: list index out of range reading/writing from/to file

Tags: python

I have got this script on Python 2.6 with RHEL OS:

```
import csv

def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = "   "      # added between columns
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    return [col_spacer.join("{0:<{1}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]


with open('pathtofile/input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
     with open('pathtofile/output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
                rows = list(csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t'))
     for row in write_cols(rows):
            f_output.write(row + '\n')
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format.py", line 26, in <module>
    for row in write_cols(rows):
  File "format.py", line 19, in write_cols
    return [col_spacer.join("{{:<{width}}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]
  File "format.py", line 19, in <genexpr>
    return [col_spacer.join("{{:<{width}}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone help me to solve this? 
I have written this script on Python 2.7 and it works fine, I am trying now to make adjustements to run on 2.6

Comment: Minor cleanup notes:  try to keep your indentation to a consistent 4 spaces.  The `with` statement will automatically close your files, no need to close them later.  Your `close` statements have no effect anyway, since you're just listing the method rather than calling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: zero length field name in format with read and write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587912/valueerror-zero-length-field-name-in-format-with-read-and-write)

Comment: It is always me, but I am having another kind of error @Ayoub

Comment: @Billy edited the question

Comment: `width=widths[index]` is throwing the error

Comment: @dnit13 I do not see why

Comment: `print widths` and then `print [ index for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data`. Your index is going out of range for widths

Comment: I am going to check immediately, but is there a reason why it works on Python 2.7? @dnit13

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128068/discussion-between-alessandro-blasetti-and-dnit13).

Comment: Oh I see .. i thought it was the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your format call here:

```
"{{:<{width}}}".format(col, width=widths[index])
```

has either too many or not enough arguments / braces. The braces in the string each indicate a place to put text for `format`. I'd say you have too many braces and it gets confused by that. You could either use different parenthesis, or remove them...

Tell me if i'm missing the point/purpose of this statement

Comment: Just edited the question modifying this part but I am having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
"{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index])
```

to this

```
"{0:<{1}}".format(col, widths[index])
```

and it will work.

Comment: This change gives me this error: IndexError: tuple index out of range . Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the help of @MartinEvans.

The problem is simplier than we could imagine: there was a blank line on the bottom of the input file.